# AJAX Lightbox Spinner PopUp to appear from Page to Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spinner, lightbox

Is there a bit of technology available that displays a Lightbox AJAX 'Spinner' in the centre of the page each time the user navigates from one page on a site to another?

**So on each 'click' of a hyperlink it would popup a spinner animation while the page loads.**

Is this easy to achieve?

**Many thanks for any pointers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few examples out there, the one that springs to mind is BlockUI though. Take a look at http://jquery.malsup.com/block . You will need to combine this with your ajax succes/error/always callbacks, but the examples should help you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#spinner').show();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#spinner').hide();
})
```

Comment: Many thanks, ManseUK. I have selected 20100 as the answer as it contains examples/demos.